# Can I conform to Hashable using different properties than used to conform to Equatable?

Tags: swift

How can I have an object have the same hash value but not equate?

```
~pseudo~

savedObj = { id: 123, status: "good" }
objects = Set<myType>()

incomingObj = { id: 123, status: "bad" }

// savedObj should not equal incomingObj but
// Should update 123 and not insert a new object
objects.update(incomingObj)
```

Here's some more proper code to dig in to this. I'm new to Swift so feel I'm just not understanding things properly.

Let's say I have a bunch of IoT wifi devices I want to scan for. They each have a unique MAC address and variable (hypothetical) status. I want to add these devices to a Set and to be able to compare a current scan against the existing Set.

```
struct Device: Hashable {
  let macAddress: String
  var status: String?

  init(mac: String) {
    macAddress = mac
  }
```

To make the devices in the Set unique, I'll use the mac address, but since the status can vary, I don't want that taken into account. So I add the following code:

```
...
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(macAddress)
  }
```

This is where I get confused and need help. If I add `device1` and `device2` to my set and then update the status on `device1` to "ready" it will be a new, third, entry into the set. I've discovered to make sure this doesn't happen I have to conform to Equatable manually:

```
...
  static func == (lhs: Device, rhs: Device) -> Bool {
    return
      lhs.macAddress == rhs.macAddress
  }
```

But that means that if I have a device in my set with no status and the mac address `device1` it would equal a secondary scan of `device1` with a status set to "ready" because I am only equating the `macAddress`. Is there any way around that? I want to insert into the set uniquely based on `macAddress` but equate based on all properties of the struct.

EDIT:
I've seen something like this statement in other SO answers, which is part of why I'm confused my code doesn't work:
"Two objects that are equal will have the same hash value, but two objects with the same hash value are not necessarily equal."

Yet I can't make the code prove that.

Comment: This is semi-commonly asked. The answer is semi-complex. I explain it all in my article, here: https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Grocery%20stores%2C%20hashing%20and%20dictionaries.md

Comment: Long story short: Use a dictionary to key by `MacAddress` (You shouldn't use `String`s for mac addresses), and don't directly hash or equate `Device`s themselves.

Comment: `Hashable` documentation states that "Two instances that are equal must feed the same values to Hasher in hash(into:), in the same order.", and `Equatable` states: "Equality implies substitutability—any two instances that compare equally can be used interchangeably in any code that depends on their values". One of your requirements violates those conformance semantics. You can implement your definition of device-equality, e.g. with a custom implementation of `.isSame` function

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica What would be the proper type for a mac address instead of String?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica (accidentally submitted previous comment early) I looked at using a dictionary, but it was causing downstream problems - or just requiring more code  I was trying to avoid - and it seemed Set should be able to solve it.

Comment: @NewDev Given that Hashable definition, why do I see comments like "All equal objects have the same hash, but not all objects with the same hash are equal"? If the `hash(with:)` must use the same properties as `func ==` I don't see how statements like that can be true. 

Is your recommendation of `.isSame` a custom function or overriding an existing function? Given the rest of the code involved, this may be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @Philip What happens next week when you get a requirement to identify devices by their serial numbers, or by their IP addresses, etc. You can only have one definition of Hashable/Equatable, which you shouldn't use in a very use-case specific way like this

Comment: @Philip isSame is a custom function he was suggesting. I'll repeat my self-promotion, I really think you should read https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Grocery%20stores%2C%20hashing%20and%20dictionaries.md . It'll explain the rules, their motivations, and what happens when you don't satisfy them. It'll answer everything you just asked

Comment: Thanks @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I am working my way through that article!

Comment: @Philip LMK if you have any feedback! I intend to direct users towards that whenever people ask questions about buggy hashing behavior.